# EF RemoveRange throws exception when given an empty list

Tags: entity-framework

I'm calling RemoveRange on an EF6 context but if the argument happens to be an empty enumeration it throws the following.

"Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is not allowed."

It seems very odd to me. Any ideas as to what is going on?